# Using Monitor instead of Android Studio built in tools

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

Under the folder structure SDK > Tools, you will find Monitor.bat. This lightweight program is reminiscent of Eclipse with the tools and how it looks. I use it for logcat because I prefer it over Android Studio's. I would also like to start using it for Debug but I do not know how to connect Monitor with Android Studio. How can I debug the application(s) I am building in Android Studio using Monitor program? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not know how to connect Monitor with Android Studio

Launch it from Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor from within Android Studio.

> How can I debug the application(s) I am building in Android Studio using Monitor program?

If by "debug" you mean stuff like breakpoints and stepping through code, you can't. That was never a feature of the Android Device Monitor.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder: "I like the stepping through better on Monitor" -- no, you don't, as there is no "stepping through" in Monitor. Eclipse offers "stepping through"-style debugging. Monitor does not. It never did, and likely it never will. Monitor is basically some of the ADT plugin, pulled out as a separate app. It is not an IDE; it is not a symbolic debugger.